# Securely create role in Postgres using SQL script and environment variables

Tags: postgresql, passwords

What is a best way to securely pass the password into Postgres SQL script to create DB ROLE?

Answer (score 7):

During the developing of the automated Postgres schema deployment I tried to find the way securely create the dbuser password, pass it to the deployment script and store it in secret manager, doesn't matter which.

The hardest part was passing and usage of the environment variable in the SQL script.
The way I found seem good and pretty secure.

Password generated using openssl:

```
export ROLE_PASSWORD=$(openssl rand -base64 12)
```

The psql command as follow:

```
psql -v password_to_save=$ROLE_PASSWORD -a -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres -f test.sql
```

The SQL script:

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
-- \echo :password_to_save

CREATE ROLE dbuser WITH
    LOGIN
    NOSUPERUSER
    NOCREATEDB
    NOCREATEROLE
    NOINHERIT
    NOREPLICATION
    CONNECTION LIMIT -1
    PASSWORD :'password_to_save';
```

As a result the password secured all the way to the implementation.